# Creating a set of orthogonal axes

Tags: matlab, axes, orthogonal

I need to create a series of vectors for a simulation which give the direction of propagation and the polarization of light (3 dimensions).  Because of that the direction and the polarization need to be orthogonal so i need something like this:

```
D= [dir1;     P=[pol11;
   dir1;         pol12;
   dir2;         pol21;
   dir2;         pol21;
   dir3;         pol31;
   .... ]        ...  ]
```

As you can see each direction has two polarizations. What is important here is that dir1*pol11'=0,dir1*pol12'=0 and so on. The directions should span the whole solid angle, while the direction of the polarization is not strictly important, though it would be nice if they where orthogonal to each other. I tried two different approaces, one is creating a basic orthogonal basis and rotating it, the other is creating a matrix of directions and using the null() function to create the polarizations. In both cases what I get is that if I do D*P' I get a series of 0s but some of the values are non zero - very small(e.g. 1e-17), but non zero nonetheless.
Code 1:

```
bDir=[1,0,0;1,0,0]
bPol=[0,1,0;0,0,1]
dir=bDir
pol=bPol
for phi=0:pi/5:2*pi
    for theta=0:pi/5:pi
        rotatePhi=[cos(phi) -sin(phi) 0;...
                         sin(phi) cos(phi) 0;...
                         0 0 1];
        rotateTheta=[cos(theta) 0 sin(theta);...
                              0 1 0;...
                              -sin(theta) 0 cos(theta)];
        rDir=bDir*rotateTheta*rotatePhi;
        rPol=bPol*rotateTheta*rotatePhi;

        dir=vertcat(dir,rDir);
        pol=vertcat(pol,rPol);

    end
end
```

Code 2:

```
bDir=[1,0,0;1,0,0]
dir=bDir
pol=[0,1,0;0,0,1]
for phi=0:pi/5:2*pi
    for theta=0:pi/5:pi
        rotatePhi=[cos(phi) -sin(phi) 0;...
                         sin(phi) cos(phi) 0;...
                         0 0 1];
        rotateTheta=[cos(theta) 0 sin(theta);...
                              0 1 0;...
                              -sin(theta) 0 cos(theta)];
        rDir=bDir*rotateTheta*rotatePhi;
        rPol=null(rDir)';

        dir=vertcat(dir,rDir);
        pol=vertcat(pol,rPol);

    end
end
```

I believe the problem is that matlab introduces some precision errors, but it might be wrong.
Can anyone tell me if there is an error in my code, or if there is a better way to obtain the 2 matricies I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectations for [floating point arithmetic](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) are a little off. Floating point arithmetic is not exact. In MATLAB typically floating point arithmetic operations are only accurate to 16 decimal places (`1e-16`). Any values smaller than this can typically be regarded as `0`.

The [`eps`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) function in MATLAB can be used to determine the smallest floating point number that MATLAB is capable of representing. On my system it produces

```
>> eps
ans =

   2.2204e-16
```

Any numbers less than this MATLAB is incapable of accurately representing.

---

As well as the accuracy of floating point arithmetic it is also typically wrong to compare them with an integer value of `0`. A more accurate comparison would be

```
if dir*pol < 1e-16
    fprintf(1, 'Orthogonal\n');
else
    fprintf(1, 'Not Orthogonal\n');
end
```

For most purposes when using floating point arithmetic and typically in MATLAB given the above output of `eps` any value less than `2.2204e-16` is effectively `0`.

---

If you do want variable precision arithmetic you can use [`vpa`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html). However, it is typically unnecessary and floating point arithmetic should suffice so long as you are aware of its downfalls.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was aware of the 'limitations'. The problem I have is that I am not directly using these values, but rather I use them as input for a toolbox, the toolbox, I am guessing, checks that the direction of and polarization are orthogonal, and when it finds it is not the case returns an error. I cannot change the toolbox (and am not sure what the results would be if I could), so i am actually looking for an alternative to obtain the directions and polarizations

Comment: Any alternative method will run into the same issues in my answer.